# Memberwise Copier

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, return

I have a question on this piece of code...Why does it keep visiting the memberwise copier

Here's the code, this is a member function of a class called `string`.

```
string operator +(string &r) {
    char *k = NULL;
    k = new char[strlen(this->getstring()) + strlen(r.getstring()) + 1];

    strcpy(k, this->getstring());
    strcat(k, r.getstring());
    string Z = k;

    delete[] k;
    return Z; // visits MemberWise Copier then destructs.. 
}
```

and here's my memberwise copier..

```
string(string &p) : s(NULL)
{
    setstring(p.getstring());
}
```

Comment: Since you're returning a string by value from this function, it needs to call the copy constructor to return that copy.  Changing operator+ to return a string& should fix that.

Comment: @medgno That would be an error, you cannot return a reference to a local variable. You need to return by value here.

Answer (score 0):

This code calls the copy-constructor of your `string` class because the string `Z` is being returned by-value. A memberwise copy will always happen when this is so.

Answer (score 0):

You return by value: this obviously calls the copy constructor (*not* the “memberwise copier” as no such thing exists in C++ parlance), by definition.

So everything is the way it’s supposed to be.

If you’re concerned about the overhead of copying the string, don’t be: all modern compilers will optimise this copy away where possible so that it’s safe and efficient to return by value (not that you have a choice: the semantics here *require* returning by value).